# Python - Compare number with boolean (always return false)

Tags: python, boolean, compare, logic

Is there some kind of keyword to use in Python, that can be logically compared to always be false?

For example, I want something like

```
None > 20
```

To return false when evaluated. Is there some keyword to use besides `None` here, since comparing a NoneType and Integer throws an error?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to achieve with this. . .some context

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I have some logic that sets the value of a key in a dictionary to be `None` if some condition is met. Later, I am using `eval` to evaluate some boolean logic, which then goes and tries to compare `None > 20` (or some other number). I actually got around this by putting eval in a try/except block, and passing the TypeError, but I'm not sure if that is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in object that does this, but you can always make your own:

```
class Thing:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return False
    #use the same function for <=, ==, >, etc
    __le__ = __eq__ = __gt__ = __ge__ = __lt__

x = Thing()
print(x < 20)
print(x <= 20)
print(x > 20)
print(x >= 20)
print(x == 20)
```

Result:

```
False
False
False
False
False
```

---

Edit: I remembered a built-in way to do this. If you only need to compare to ordinary numbers, you can use the special "Not a Number" floating point value:

```
x = float("nan")
print(x < 20)
print(x <= 20)
print(x > 20)
print(x >= 20)
print(x == 20)
```

Result:

```
False
False
False
False
False
```

And if you specifically only want `x > 20` to return False and don't particularly care what the other comparisons return, it may make more sense to use the special "negative infinity" floating point value.

```
>>> x = float("-inf")
>>> x > 20
False
```

Comment: Does float("nan") also return false when used in an inequality operation? I need it to return false for `float("nan") != 20`

Comment: Let's see... Nope, `float("nan") != 20` evaluates to True. Looks like you'll have to define your own type after all. (don't forget to add `__ne__` to the `__le__ = __eq__ = ...` chain)